# Port existing obj c code to swift - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to use obj c library in swift but I am having issue with the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I think that I am missing something in `var annotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!` declaration is wrong but can't find a way around.
Code is:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
var annotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

        if(annotation is KPAnnotation){

            var kingpinAnnotation = annotation as KPAnnotation

            if (kingpinAnnotation.isCluster()){

                annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("cluster") as MKPinAnnotationView // THIS IS THE ERROR LINE

                if (annotationView == nil) {
                    annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: kingpinAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "cluster")
                }

                annotationView.pinColor = .Purple;

            } else {

                annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin") as MKPinAnnotationView

                if (annotationView == nil) {
                    annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: kingpinAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

                }

                annotationView.pinColor = .Red;

            }

            annotationView.canShowCallout = true;

            return annotationView;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please specify which rule produces the error? You unwrap multiple optionals. Which of the optionals you unwrap does matter to the answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "forced cast" `as MKPinAnnotationView` (to a *non-optional* type)  aborts with a runtime exception
if `mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier()` returns `nil`.

You can use an optional cast `as?` instead:

```
annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("cluster")
                      as? MKPinAnnotationView
```

which assigns `nil` to `annotationView` in that case.

If it is guaranteed that all elements in the reuse queue have the type
`MKPinAnnotationView` then a cast to an *implicitly unwrapped optional*
would work as well:

```
annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("cluster")
                      as MKPinAnnotationView!
```

but the first version is the safer one.